# Show that $\|A^{-1}\|\leq \|A\|^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Suppose that $A$ is a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\|A^{-1}\|\leq \|A\|^{n-1}$.

By $\|A\|$, I mean the operator norm $\displaystyle\sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Av\|$.

Comment: @SangchulLee the "largest modulus of eigenvalues" function is **not** a matrix norm (that is, it isn't submultiplicative).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, You are right. I guess my intuition is always based on some nice matrices (such as normal matrices) and often I do silly mistakes like this :(...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof for the Euclidean norm. This approach is buried in Schäffer. J., "[Norms and determinants of linear mappings](http://repository.cmu.edu/math/163/)", Technical report, CMU, Department of Mathematical Sciences, 1970. He does not use the SVD, but the
idea is essentially the same.

Let $A=U \Sigma V^*$ be a singular value decomposition of $A$, with $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag} (\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$, and $\sigma_1\ge ... \ge\sigma_n$.

Then $\|A\| = \sigma_1, \|A^{-1}\| = {1 \over \sigma_n}$, and
$|\det A| = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$.

Hence $|\det A| \le \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_{n-1} {1 \over \|A^{-1} \|} \le \|A\|^{n-1} {1 \over \|A^{-1} \|}$, from which we obtain
$|\det A| \|A^{-1} \| \le \|A\|^{n-1}$.

The result is not true for general operator norms, for example, with
$A=\begin{bmatrix} {1 \over 2} & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, we have
$\det A = 1$, $\|A^{-1} \|_\infty = 3, \|A\|_\infty  = 2$ and so
$3=\|A^{-1} \|_\infty \not< \|A\|_\infty^{2-1} = 2$.

As an aside, it is worth noting the related [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality), $|\det A| \le \|Ae_1\| \cdots \|A e_n\|$ (Euclidean norm).